# Backbone.js - persisting data after back button

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning backbone.js to add some interactivity to an existing web app. On initial page load I'm bootstrapping some initial data into the page, using the `reset()` method [suggested in the docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap). This works great. I can also create new model instances, and the view handles them just as I would expect; they show up alongside the initial data, and everything is fine. (The new data also hits the database just fine.)

However, if I click on a link to a different page (not using backbone routes or anything, just a normal link) and then hit my browser's back button, the new models I created previously are gone; only the old initial data shows up. I've done some debugging and found that the `reset()` method runs each time the page is loaded, so presumably that's what's nuking the additional data I'd added. (However, if I actually *refresh* the page, the new data will be displayed again, since now it's getting bootstrapped in too.)

I know I could use `fetch()` to get the newly-added data (along with the older data), but I'm trying to avoid that, both because (a) that's an extra request every time the page is loaded, and (b) because the docs say that's not ideal.

So, what should I do so that using the back button doesn't make stuff (temporarily) vanish?

Comment: A no cache browser directive maybe?

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out, @peppergrower? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Page loads models, views, collections and Routers. Page set's up the collection through `reset`(bootstrapping). User clicks link to navigate to another page, clicks the back button. Something interesting happens now,

- Routers match the url before the page is loaded ( when clicking back button). During this match you must verify that the collection contains new data and then do `collection.fetch()`.
- This will make you get latest always and hit the server only once (Either your collection is empty or it does not contain fresh data)